# What exactly is happening in Wonder Woman 06 (2012)? What is the point of this entire story arc?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, wonder-woman

So I was reading up on the New-52 stories of Wonder Woman, as I heard quite good things about it. So far it was pretty enjoyable, but the entire story arc starting in 05 running to the end of 06 (the one were WW is playing Poseidon and Hades to do ... something to Hera) kinda escapes me.

From what I can tell, WW and her posse create an elaborate ruse to lure Hera to a joint meeting with Poseidon and Hades. Then this happens:

[image: ![WW scan 1]][2]

[image: WW scan 2]

Soooo ... WW goes to great lengths to lure Hera to a place to ... send her back again into her home?

**What am I missing here? What does WW even need Hades' light for? Why did she even need Poseidon at the same place anyway?**

It kinda seems like WW was breaking Hera's magic mirror, or whatever the round thing in the last panel was. But ... is that it? If so, why is that worth so much effort?

Comment: Based on just these panels. It looks like Hera is using the pool to project herself somewhere. WW uses the Hades' light to break the pool/mirror, disrupting her ability to project herself elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell (warning, I'm no WW expert), Hera is using the magic mirror in the lower panel to astrally project her image to where Wonder Woman and the other children of Zeus are hanging out. Wonder Woman uses Hermes' staff to teleport to Mount Olympus and smashes the mirror with one of the candles from Hades head while Hera is distracted, thus preventing her from viewing what's happening on Earth or traveling as projected energy.

Poseidon spells out quite neatly what the effect was, to blind Hera;

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that seems a lot of effort just to inconvenience Hera in her travels (given that she's a goddess, I assume she still has means to travel back and fro between Mt. Olympus and the mortal world). But I agree that this is probably what is happening here. Any thoughts about why WW needed Poseidon in the meeting (or even Hera)? It seems just luring Hades somewhere, stealing one of his candles, and teleporting to Olympus seems ... easier.

Comment: It was just to lure Hera out into the real world.